# How to check whether all the elements in a column have same text?

Tags: android, listview

I have 2 text views textview1 and textview2 in a custom list view. The total number of rows in the listview is 10. If all the elements in the textview 2 have a value namely "true". When the 10th element's textview1 is clicked, it should display a message "Success" or even if one textview2 has a value other than "true", then 10th element textview1 on click should display a message "Failure".

Here is my code 
    package com.example.list;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
ListView lv;
private  static boolean test= false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);   
    lv.setAdapter(new slist(this));         
}

public class slist extends BaseAdapter
{
     private Context context;

      public slist(Context c) 
      {
           context = c;
      }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {           
          return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {           
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {           
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

           LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
           v = li.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);

           final TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
           final TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

           t1.setText(names[position]);
           t2.setText(bikes[position]);


           t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
           {                
            public void onClick(View v)
             {
                    if(t1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(names[names.length-1]))
                {

                 //Here i should loop through and check all the elements in the bikes[] 
                }
                else
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

             }
           });

           return v;
    }

}

String [] names = { "rams", "venu", "pavan", "sravan", "vishnu", "krishna", "hari", "prasad", "raghu" };
    String [] bikes = { "true", "true", "false", "true", "true", "false", "true", "false", "true" };
```

}

Comment: You can always rely on the model data given to the adapter and do some String comparisons, instead of relying on the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following piece of code

```
 t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       {                
        public void onClick(View v)
         {
    //check for the position of last item
    if(position==(names.length-1))
    {
        //check for second element of other 9 items
        for(int i=0;i<bikes.length-1;i++)
        {

            if(bikes[i].equals("true"))
            {
                result=true;
            }
            else
            {
                result=false;
            }
        }
    }
         }
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 index=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    View view=yourlistviewname.getChildAt(index);
    TextView tv1=view.findViewByID(R.id.textview1);
    TextView tv2=view.findViewByID(R.id.textview2);

    String first=tv1.getText().toString();
    String second=tv2.getText().toString();  

 if(first.equals("yourArrayItemHere")){
 //your message here
 }
 if(second.equals("false")){
 //your message here
 }
```

and You can set the message 'success' or 'failure' as per your textview's text;

Comment: I have to loop through all the 9 tv2's. If all the tv2 have same text, then i have to display success or failure.

Comment: so what is the problem to loop your tv2?

Comment: Hi neurenor, why to loop through the views of the list. because you already have the data list which you will be giving to the adapter of the list. you can rely on that right?.

Comment: How do i design a for loop to check the String ?

Comment: he wants to check in all 10 tvs not a particular.so that i suggests him this.i know that if he wants to get only one tvs than he can set a Tag on that tvs on click event and get particular tv by using the Tag we have set.

Comment: The problem is i have to display message after the for loop.

Comment: checkout the edited answer.you just need to put your message there.

Comment: you have used getView method so there is no need to loop through all.just put the code as i wrote.check out edited answer.and yes do not forget to set the Tag.write this code above the onClick listener.
tv1.setTag(i);